# Remove the "Range" HTTP header with squid

Tags: http-headers, squid

I am using squid 3.2.5 and I would like to configure it such that it removes the "Range" HTTP header from all incoming GET requests.
From [this](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201205/0016.html) post, I understand that this can be done using the "range_offset_limit" option. I have tried adding the following to the squid configuration file:

```
acl GET method GET
range_offset_limit none GET
```

I also tried with just:

```
range_offset_limit none
```

, but none of the configurations seem to work.

Any idea on how I could accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the "request_header_access" directive does the trick:

```
request_header_access Range deny all
```

This also has the advantage that it works with older versions of squid.